# Rewrite JPA query to improve performence

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entities: `parent (id integer, ...)` and `child(id integer, parent_id integer, ...)`
I have JPA Specification that build query in method
`toPredicate(Root<Child> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb)`. This query looks like

```
select ch.*
   from child ch
      inner join parent pr on ch.parent_id = pr.id
   where ch.field1 = ?
     and ch.field2 = ?
     and pr.field1 = ?
     ... other simple conditions
  order by field
  limit 50 offset 750000
```

This query works 18 seconds, index doesn't work. But I run sql-query like

```
select ch.*
   from (select * 
         from child
         where ch.field1 = ?
           and ch.field2 = ?
           and ...) as ch
      inner join (select * 
                  from parent 
                  where pr.field1 = ? 
                    and ...) pr on ch.parent_id = pr.id
   where 
    ... other simple conditions
  order by field
  limit 50 offset 750000
```

This query works 3 sec.

**Question:**
Can I realize the second query in method `toPredicate(...)` ?

**Environment**

- PostgreSQL 9.6
- Spring Data JPA 1.11.11.RELEASE
- Spring 4.3.16.RELEASE
- Hibernate 5.2.2.Final

Comment: In your database IDE, have you tried using `EXPLAIN` to show the execution plan of the two statements? This should give you some insight into why you're missing the index hit.